# Php randomly stopped working?

Tags: php

I'm on Linux and I decided to go ahead and install an application called Aptana Studio 3. It looks to actually just be the eclipse IDE with some plugins, but that's neither here nor there.

Ever since I've done that my PHP doesn't work.

For a server I've used XAMPP.

```
<php? 
    echo "Hello World";
?>
```

The above code won't show anything.

using require 'badnamehere.php' doesn't throw errors, the SQL structure that I have written isn't doing anything..

The php is simply being ignored, and I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Perhaps because your opening tag is incorrect? It should be `<?php` and not `<php?`

Comment: Didn't notice it as that's the tag that was generated by the IDE.. Not to mention it's my first day with PHP, thanks, fixed it.. I'll change the settings for the IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrong PHP syntax `<php?`

try this one

```
<?php
    echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Comment: Didn't notice it as that's the tag that was generated by the IDE.. Not to mention it's my first day with PHP, thanks, fixed it.. I'll change the settings for the IDE